# Are questions about source control off topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why is [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200896/good-place-to-upload-files) considered off topic?

I choose to be fair and show all reasons why I dislike the current options - would've it been ontopic if I simply lied and only told I was dissatisfied with googlecode? That's hiding from information and should actually be worse than someone who is fair and open in his mindset I think?

Furthermore: isn't it completely stupid that people up/downvote about how someone THINKS instead of up/downvote for the quality of the question? Considering the massive userbase of stackexchange I do not think downvoting should be done when someone hates something you love.

Comment: off-topic close reason doesn't feel right to me; not constructive would be the better match: "...this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". It is quite likely that OT was selected as an unfortunate vote split

Answer (score 6):

I was the final closer on this one.  There are several aspects to this question that makes it... difficult to fit into the Q&A format for P.SE.

1. Legal questions about international law need to be answered by people trained in international law - lawyers.  Not programmers.  You likely need to first talk to a lawyer in your jurisdiction to actually determine what the options are and if there are any sites that do meet the requirements you have.
2. The question is strongly influenced by current events.  The question of "NSA snooping" may not be applicable next year (it may, but it may not). This makes it localized to a time (and place - your countries laws may be influencing it, see #1 above).
3. It has a rant in the question that continues into the comments.  This is encouraging debate - something the QA format is not well suited for.
4. Resource request - assuming that there are sites that fit your requirements, there are multiple such sites.  This leads the question to be not constructive because there are multiple equally right answers that are not the same.

Comment: 1. The question was SPURRED by legal problems. in an attempt to EVADE legal problems. as for 2: no the question remains next year, as I've learned from resent events that there's no way to trust anything except for your own area of influence.... Also about resource requests? The most popular questions are often the questions talking about good books etc - that's much more a "resource request" thing than this.

Comment: For legal questions and problems, you had best ask someone who is an expert in the legal field.  On resource requests you may wish to read [Are book recommendations on-topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/) and [Are “I'm looking for X” questions on topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/) - the popularity of the question doesn't mean it is a good fit.  I would encourage you to look at the questions asking for books and their current state.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't vote on the question, but it reeds too much like a rant against Google to me. That is probably the reason for closing it as "Off Topic".

However, removing the ranting bits is not sufficient to get the question into shape, because the remaining core will likely solicit debate or be seen as a resource request.

Answer (score 3):

I had a vote in that one.

Looking back on it, the question is better suited being closed as "Not Constructive". Also, as far as I know, source control questions are better suited on another site.

Either way, the question should have been closed.

Comment: Where? Isn't programmers exactly about all side aspect of programming that doesn't fall under the "how do I make XY" umbrella?

Comment: @paul23 Programmers is best suited for "whiteboard development" questions. Questions on Programmers are supposed to be conceptual questions directly related to programming. For more information on what topics are on/off topic, [check out the help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).